# Is there an out-of-universe reason for the Gundam series mech head designs?

Tags: culture, gundam

As I watch the shows I am constantly noticing the patterns in the head designs of the mobile suits.

Any true Gundam, or otherwise important mech, will always have two eyes and usually the V horns.
Any generic suit, or one belonging to a more shallow villain, will only have one eye.

Is this any kind of cultural reference?

EDIT

In Unicorn characters say that a mech becomes a Gundam when the horn opens into a V.  As if the V horns are something very specific.

Comment: This question is a bit broad. What are you basing this off of? Certain series might share a mech designer.

Comment: looking at the gundams [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iwBei.jpg) seem very similar to [samurai helmets](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=samurai+helmet&es_sm=93&biw=1366&bih=667&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI8L7WppzsyAIVSctjCh0Mlgb2) and one could see any human piloted mecha as giant futuristic samurai armour

Answer (score 3):

[According to Kunio Okawara](http://www.nationmultimedia.com/business/Simplicity-key-to-successful-design-30259167.html), the mecha designer for the series:

> "I also put the form of the [chonmage](http://haircutpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Chonmage), which is a form of Japanese traditional haircut worn by men, and [kabuto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabuto), which is a type of helmet first used by ancient Japanese warriors, into the design of Gundam. They are my inspirations that are concealed behind the creation of Gundam."

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Helmet_(kabuto),_Edo_period,_mid-18th_century,_repouss%C3%A9_iron.JPG]
[image: chonmage]

[image: RX-78-2 Head]

Answer (score 0):

the gundam head design is supposed to be a homage to samurai helmets: designed to intimidate opponents (which is why a lot of characters get scared seeing a gundam head).

prettymuch all gundam head designs have a V shaped antenna on the forhead (barring the turn A gundam, which reminds me of world war 1 german nobility/soldier); two vents on the moutpiece (barring zeta, exia, 00 Qan[t] and a few others); generally have white as the main colour, a red/black small beard, blue/green/yellow eyes, and a square element atop the head
quite bizzarely a lot of japanese car designers pay homage to gundam for their car design